# AND operator while assignment

Tags: python, and-operator

What does this means :

```
>>> a = 12 and 13
>>> a
13
```

How does `and` operator works while assigning values or is just that it takes the last value ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the expression on the left of `and` is false, it will be returned. Otherwise, `and` returns the value on the right:

```
0 and 13
Out[3]: 0

12 and 13
Out[4]: 13
```

You should think about how this works- check all the combinations of True/False on the left and right, and you'll see that having `and` work this way means the value it returns always reflects the True/False status of both expressions.

Answer (score 0):

[short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) 
The opposite:

```
>>> a = 12 or 13
>>> a
12
```